Please help me with this complex shape
I cannot wrap my head around on how to create this pistol grip
The model is CZ P 10 F
I've tried many times and it just doesn't work/look good. I have to model high poly with a lowpoly in mind so I can easily simplify the mesh later.
I highlighted areas that I'm stuck at. Its that organic indent for a thumb and also the transition from a very rounded grip into a squareish trigger guard area. Also I have to somehow insert sharp edged trigger guard into a very smooth body.
It doesn't need to be all quads subd. If I could I would use ZBrush live boolean pipeline. I could also use plasticity for the slide. My biggest problem is the grip and I cannot progress any further.
Do I create a very blocky basic shape of the gun, apply 1 level of subd and somehow refine it later?
I need good shading on a lowpoly and a good highpoly that has all those distinct feautures of this grip. I created a 1911 gun but the modeling was super easy since its all made out of very simple shapes. I challenged myself and I failed.
I tried everything. Zbrush, Plasticity solid modeling, Plasticity surface modeling. I cannot get the desired result with any of these.




i would try it with proportional editing and/or sculpting.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
